# Azure Data Factory : Pagination Rules from Header

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm playing with some Azure functionality and trying to get Pagination within ADF working.

As per my playing with "Logic Apps", I am trying to use [FreshService API](https://api.freshservice.com/#pagination) to grab some data.

I can successfully get my data, convert and write it to SQL, but at the moment i'm using an "Until" loop to iterate the pages (Exiting when the data count is < page size).

I can see that Pagination Rules are there, but can't seem to find out how to grab/check on the Headers value from the HTTP Response to find the next value.

Appreciate any thoughts/direciton

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, this feature is not available in the Azure data factory.

As a workaround, you can iterate the Until activity till the connector stops iterating.

> As per the [pagination rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#pagination-support), the connector stops iterating when it returns Http status code – 204.

Comment: Thanks. I've got pagination working with a untill loop. This is done be grabbing a known qty of records and looping untill the qty returned is < requested qty. Was just making sure I didn't miss anything.